# How do we extract the hour value in 24 hours format from a DateTime value with time stored as 12 hours format with AM and PM?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column with where dateTime stamp is present. Want to extract the value of the hour in 24 hours format while the time value stored in the field is in 12 Hours format, in AM and PM.

Comment: unless you stored explicitly the time as text, it's never stored with AM and PM in memory. That's the output format that defines what's printed out

Comment: `extract(hour from the_column)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, won't it give me the hour of lets say 2 PM as 2 while I wanted it to show 14?

Comment: It will give you 14: http://rextester.com/KMOI3090  The date and time information is _stored_ without any format attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, You use the function to_char and set the parameter `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`.

Check this query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM table_name;
```